# Combining Two Dom Elements as One with Regards to Mouse Events

Tags: javascript, mouseleave, mouseenter

I have two divs on top of everything positioned next to each other.

[image]

I'd like for the sake of mouseenter and mouseleave that they be treated as "one". They line up next to each other (or overlap).

Is this possible?

I've tried doing a mouseleave/mouseenter combo but I can't guarantee which will trigger first, the leave from the first element or the enter to its buddy.

Thanks SO!

Comment: Can't you just nest the smaller div and position it outside with absolute positioning? Then you could just apply enter/leave to the containing div.

Comment: Put a div around both and use that.

Comment: Will try the first comment. :D

Comment: Trying the first comment but coming up where to put that second div is a PITA. I'd rather use an existing element on the page that is aligned with the bigger box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onmouseleave has an event property {{toElement}} to tell you what element it is entering.

You just need to check to see if it is not the other element

```
$( function(){

  var box1 = $("#box1");
  var box2 = $("#box2");

  box1.add(box2).mouseenter( function(){
      box1.css("background-color","#CFC");  
      box2.css("background-color","#DED");  
  }).mouseleave( function(e){
      var domElem = e.toElement;
      if(domElem==box1[0] || domElem==box2[0] ) return;
      box1.add(box2).css("background-color","#CCC");
  });


});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vB67g/)